# convert curl to angular 12 Http request

Tags: angular

How to covert `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/coupons -u sk_test_51L0g7yIrxFS2pGNOV1amLmGXMi0KatOjReDerQFeYE0jrIJZRaVEcODVN4KrMtx9BB2H7LJs5RSIZp8A0fybjgXh00Tma1Mkvt:` this to angular http request

Comment: The official Angular site has an overview of their `HttpClient` here https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

First you should see what method the coupons use. Its get or post? Second you should check more about [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) in angular documentation and finally you need to implement the Authentication mechanism.

For example if it is a get method and you have the token you will implement a service like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '/src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StripeService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  public getCoupons() : any {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + environment.stripeKey,
    });

    const options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.get('https://api.stripe.com/v1/coupons', options);
  }

}
```